# Is it possible to convert an physical Arch Linux installation to an Arch Linux iso?

Tags: arch-linux, windows, hard-disk, iso, disk-image

For an analogy Windows has disk2vhd to take an image of an existing Windows install.

Is the same possible for Arch Linux and then convert that image to an installable Arch Linux iso.

Comment: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Archiso seems relevant

Answer (score 0):

I've not used it myself but you might want to look into Systemback: https://github.com/shadichy/systemback-archlinux

It looks like "Live system create" is the option you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks @meijin3. This looks promising however I can only accept your answer after trial.

Answer (score 0):

[Penguin's eggs](https://github.com/pieroproietti?tab=repositories) allows you to create your own live remix for backup or redistribution to others,even on archlinux platform.